# how to create a script with curley brackets using autokey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to create a script that'll type {{'
and I can't get it to write my {{

Here's my code:

```
^1::
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future 
AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and 
reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
Send ,{{'
```

Comment: See [Escape Sequences](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm#Escape_Sequences).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to only send the text, then try using Text mode like so:

```
SendInput {text}{{'
```